# Laravel "Use of undefined constant forum - assumed 'forum'" error

Tags: php, laravel

web.php

```
Route::get('/index/{forum}/{php}/{framework}/questions', function($forum, $php, $framework){
    return view('questions')->with('forum', $forum)->with('php', $php)->with('framework', 
$framework);
});
```

questions.blade.php

```
1. = {{forum}} / 2. = {{php}} / 3. = {{framework}}
```

I'm trying this but i get this error.

Comment: Please ALWAYS show us ALL the erro rmessage and not a summary. Error messages normally come with line numbers and filename of where an error occurs

Answer (score 3):

Blade curly braces are basically PHP echo function, so act accordingly

```
1. = {{ $forum }} / 2. = {{ $php }} / 3. = {{ $framework }}
```

Calling a variable without the `$` dollar sign is reserved for constants and you haven't defined such constants

Here's what happens in the background of this Blade line

```html
1. = <?php echo e(forum); ?> / 2. = <?php echo e(php); ?> / 3. = <?php echo e(framework); ?>

<?php /**PATH resources/views/welcome.blade.php ENDPATH**/ ?>
```

You can see that `forum`, `php` and `framework` are called as constants here, while you want to output variables

```php
1. = <?php echo e($forum); ?> / 2. = <?php echo e($php); ?> / 3. = <?php echo e($framework); ?>

<?php /**PATH resources/views/welcome.blade.php ENDPATH**/ ?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: '*You can see that forum, php and framework are constants here*' - Slight point here, they're *not* constants rather the interpreter assumes them to be constants (as it can't be anything else) thus causing the '*undefined constant [...]*'.

Comment: Called as constants?

Comment: Yes, they're called as constants, that makes more sense.