# how to use script code in <script type="text/html"> </script> in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have use this code https://codepen.io/saper639/details/YzzJpBv in my laravel project.

But in html use this code:

```
<script type="text/html">
        <tr data-index="$index">
          <td>{{index+1}}</td>
          <td>{{id}}</td>
          <td class='edit' data-type='textbox' data-field='firstname'>{{firstname}}</td>
          <td class='edit' data-type='textbox' data-field='lastname'>{{lastname}}</td>
          <td class='edit' data-type='dropdown' data-field='color_id' data-source='arr_colors'>{{color_id|select(arr_colors)}}</td>
          <td><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-flat btn-xs' data-bind="rem__click:remRow"  data-id='$index' title='Удалить запись'><i class='fa fa-fw fa-remove'></i></button></td>        
        </tr>
      </script>
```

After add this code in laravel, Show this error:

```
Use of undefined constant index - assumed 'index' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
```

How to issue this error?

Comment: If that is blade template file, you should try with `$index` instead.

Comment: variables inside {{ }} you still need add dollar sign ex: {{ $variable }}

{{ }} is like as echo a variable

Comment: [Laravel "Use of undefined constant forum - assumed 'forum'" error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58307868/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is interpreting the **{{index+1}}** in your script tag as a Blade directive, but **index** is not defined in Blade templates by default.

You can change **{{index+1}}** to **@{{index+1}}** to not interpret it

```php
<script type="text/html">
    <tr data-index="@{{index}}">
        <td>@{{index+1}}</td>
        <td>@{{id}}</td>
        <td class='edit' data-type='textbox' data-field='firstname'>@{{firstname}}</td>
        <td class='edit' data-type='textbox' data-field='lastname'>@{{lastname}}</td>
        <td class='edit' data-type='dropdown' data-field='color_id' data-source='arr_colors'>@{{color_id|select(arr_colors)}}</td>
        <td><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-flat btn-xs' data-bind="rem__click:remRow"  data-id='$index' title='Удалить запись'><i class='fa fa-fw fa-remove'></i></button></td>        
    </tr>
</script>
```